# Does Amazon RDS support for CDC?

Tags: etl

I'm trying to take advantage of Change data capture to implement an ETL, that push my sql data into a triplestore (RDF). One of the database i have to deal with is an Amazon SQL RDS. I red the documentation but i could not find anything about it. Does anyone had the experience of extracting change with Amazon SQL RDS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, and for those that come after me and find this question... In 2012, AWS said that it is *not* possible to enable Change Data Capture on Amazon SQL Server RDS. See the forum post below.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=381774

The actual response from AWS:

> Unfortunately, this functionality is not currently supported as the feature requires sysadmin privileges which are not currently granted to the user in RDS.

Comment: On this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html it says "Amazon RDS currently does not support the following SQL Server features: ... Change Data Capture (CDC) - Consider using Change Tracking as an alternative to CDC." I've not looked at Change Tracking. This MS doc compares the two https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280519(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 5):

CDC is now available through the recent enhancements to the RDS

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/fast-easy-free-sync-rds-to-redshift/

Comment: Unfortunately that is for MySQL only. CDC is not supported in Microsoft SQL Server on RDS. It's not really clear from the OP's question though which flavour he's actually using. "Amazon SQL RDS" is mentioned, but what is that? It's not a product. Amazon RDS is the managed database server, and within that you can use MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, Aurora, MariaDB and Oracle.